# What. or What? is the question

Tags: punctuation

If I make the statement, "what a joke" do I have to put a question mark at the end of the sentence because it starts with "what"

Comment: You should put an exclamation mark (!), since it's not a question, but an exclamation. What a wonderful world!

Answer (score 2):

You would put a period or an exclamation mark at the end of the sentence, because to put a question mark would change the meaning, and I don't think you intend this as a question.

"What a joke!" -> This thing certainly is a joke.

"What a joke." -> Same thing, perhaps less forcefully.

"What a joke?" -> I think that this thing is a joke, but perhaps I'm not sure, or perhaps I'm asking for your input. This sentence is not commonly seen with a question mark after it.

So, the presence of 'what' in the sentence does not necessarily make the sentence a question. It all depends on the use of the word and the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

To comment on the first answer, I agree with the usage for the exclamation, but there are several issues that I can see.

> What a joke!

This statement would usually be used in a flippant (not serious, usually disrespectful) manner. I would only reserve this use if you are trying to express a serious displeasure.

> What a joke.

The same concept can be used from above, but this would be expressed in a monotone fashion.

> What a joke?

As a native speaker, trying to say this makes my mouth pucker! I would consider this phrase an incomplete sentence. This phrase does not have the format of a question.

Comment: Great answer. Welcome to ELL and thanks for putting in the time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

You can think of this meaning, "What a joke that is!" It may not be obvious why one would use the word "what" here. I find it difficult to explain. Maybe it should just be considered as an idiom.

**Examples**

What a strange profession [he has]!

What a wonderful world [this is]!

What fun [we are having tonight]!

What a great band [the Beatles were]!

If you look in the dictionary you will see an explanation such as this:

> adj.
>
> 1. ...
> 2. Whatever: They soon repaired what damage had been done.
> 3. **How great; how astonishing: What a fool!**
>
> https://www.thefreedictionary.com/what

Frankly I don't find that explanation very convincing but it shows that (in the opinion of this dictionary) "what" can be an adjective. Other dictionaries claim it is a determiner.